# What is the difference between setAll and addAll in javaFX?

Tags: javafx

I tried to add an object to a TableView in JavaFX. Then I saw that there is "setAll" and "addAll". So my question is what the difference between these two functions is.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html

Answer (score 4):

That's quite simple. "setAll" removes all previous elements before the new ones are added and "addAll" does just that. It adds all the elements to the already existing ones.